# AWS EC2 - Can we restrict(decrease) the max storage volume limit allocated per region in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Scenario:

```
 - t2.micro instances : Amazon Linux AMI
 - Number of instances : 15
 - Volumes
   root Volume : 8GiB
   Additional EBS Volume : 10000 GiB
```

When i am trying to launch the Ec2 instances, i am getting following error:

> Launch Failed
>  You have exceeded your maximum gp2 storage limit of 100 TiB in this region. Please contact AWS Support to request an Elastic
>   Block Store service limit increase.
>  *Hide launch log*
>  
>   Creating security groups    Successful (sg-0567946d12185cda5)
>  Authorizing inbound rules Successful 
>   Initiating launches Failure ***Retry***

I know why this error came up. In the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) its clearly mentioned that the

> Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) Limits: Total volume storage
>   of General Purpose SSD (gp2) volumes - Defailt Limit is 100 TiB

For increasing limit as mentioned in error message i have to contact AWS.

**Is there any way by which i can decrease this limit?**

Comment: Just submit a ticket for increasing the limit

Comment: Hi Reza, I am looking for decreasing the limit. not increasing!

Comment: Check the John Rotenstein answer

Comment: "Decreasing the limit" means that you get LESS storage. If you wish to increase storage, then you will need to _increase_ the limit. It's pretty unusual to want 100TB of storage, but you seem to want 15 x 100TB! Why do you need so much storage and what are you going to do with it? There might be a better way, such as using Amazon S3.

Comment: Actually scenario I explained above is something I don't want to happen.. I don't want my aws team to provision those kind of instances even by mistake. So it's better to proactively reduce size and make sure that scenario never happens.. one of the aws team member did create these kind of instances and it's a billing nightmare .. The request I raised for decreasing stoarage limit is still not processed by AWS. Waiting for them to come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Amazon EC2 management console, click **Limits** in the left navigation pane.

Scroll down to **EBS Limits** to view the current limits.

You can request an increase/decrease of the limits by clicking **Request limit increase**.

[image: EBS Limits]

Comment: Thank you for providing details. I just raised a request for decreasing the limit. On call with AWS Support now. I will update further once the request is processed.

Comment: AWS support has processed my request for decreasing the limit. Screenshot added. https://snag.gy/8Myjul.jpg .. Thank you for the help :)